# the library 'transformers' works also with older version of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, transformer

i am working with Tensorflow version 1.14 and i would like to use the bert embedding. 
In order to do so, i was thinking to use the transformers library( https://pypi.org/project/transformers/)  but i am not sure if that will work with my tensorflow version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work but I recommend using TF2 for any new developments. In the end, if something does not work, you will have to port it back to TF2. Even though there are not significant difference in the semantics of the framework